# Content width on mod election pages exceeds width

Tags: bug, design

Please take a look [at the current selection of possible mods](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election). In detail: Brian Fegters list.

There's also the problem that the buttons don't align in width:

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. (filler txt)

Comment: But if you refresh the page where someone else is at the top they all overflow too far not just Brian's

Comment: Sweet. I'm not the culprit.

Comment: @Brady, I think it might be that tracking script you inserted that's breaking the markup.

Comment: See Update. I guess the buttons are breaking it...

Comment: @kaiser - nice first choice ;)

Comment: @Brady - you're 2nd :) Upvote appreciated ;)